# Can't SSH to my dedicated server on Centos 7

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall, centos7

Can't SSH to my dedicated server on Centos 7(Unmanaged)

I saw this error & i rebooted my server and couldn't connect/SSH anymore

I messed up some configuration, not sure what to do. i see this error and after rebooted i can't access

```
sudo: pam_open_session: Error in service module
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

This is from support team reply :

> But all ports are filtered:
>
> ```
> Nmap scan report for **** (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx)
> Host is up.
> All 1000 scanned ports on **** (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) are filtered
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 51.35 seconds
> ```
>
> I would suggest to access via rescue mode and check the firewall
> configuration.

I did rescue mode reboot and how do i reset firewall rule or how can fix it ?

Comment: Did you backup the config files you were editing? Always cp the original file to a backup when you are experimenting. Alternatively, look in the directory where the file is and see if your editor created a (.) or ~ backup file you can revert to. You may need to do 'ls -la' to see them.

Comment: Sorry i don't have a config file backup
I am on rescue mode login , i did mount also , still trying to figure out the issue
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: sudo has nothing to do with SSH. Do you have a problem with your SSH login, or do you have a problem with sudo after you connected with SSH? If it's the former, please run your ssh client with verbose output (`ssh -vvv`) and provide the output. In both cases relevant messages from the log files would be helpful, you should be able to access them in the rescue mode.

Comment: Yes i can't ssh to my system anymore, i am on rescue mode and mostly no commands work ssh -vvv on rescue mode what i see

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a port like "22" for connecting, you have to check the following:

- check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see if the proper port is there (The setting is Port)
- if you use a different port, it means you should have `policycoreutils-python` or alterates and use `semanage port` command to add it.
- check your firewall ( `firewall-cmd --list-all` ) to see if that port is in the firewall
- if it's not there, add it `firewall-cmd --add-port **PortNumber**/tcp` and make it permanent `firewall-cmd --add-port **PortNumber**/tcp --permanent`
- restart the needed services (`service sshd restart` and `firewall-cmd --reload`)

Comment: i am on rescue mode , does this change going to help ? @Overmind

Comment: You don't need to change the port. Just make sure the one you use is on the sshd_config and in the firewall.

Comment: i checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config it has port 22 
but i used different port & also semanage port is not working on rescue mode. So does firewall-cmd --list-all also.

Comment: Let it 22 and add that in the FW if it's not there.

Comment: Never mind, i could not figure it out & i am new to sysadmin things , i have reinstalled everything (centos 7) & as it was new system & very less data to loss. Thanks for your reply